# Calculate cover loss between years using r.mapcalc

Tags: raster, grass-gis, land-cover

I am working on forest cover raster data for 2 years and am interested in areas with >5% loss in forest cover. I am pretty new in GRASS GIS, so any suggestions for how to create a difference map of two years using r.mapcalc?

by the way, I have used zonal statistics in qgis, to calculate % cover in each year.

Comment: can you elaborate on the data you wish to use with `r.mapcalc`? Is it NDVI data? Is it the output of your zonal, what are the values stand for? How did you compute % cover, what are the zones?

Comment: I use raster maps derived from MODIS VCF data. I used zonal statistics to calculate the percent cover in each year based on boundaries of my area of interest. I have been told to use g.region rast and then r.mapcalc for subtraction of the cover maps. So far I have not proceed much more anyhow...